# How to temporarily hide inactive pages in a UIScrollView

Tags: ios, uiview, uiscrollview

I have a UIScrollView with 10+ pages configured in a way that contents from 3 pages will always appear on a screen at a time (screenshot below).

[image]

For a feature, I need to temporarily disable the inactive pages on the screen, and I was wondering if there is a way to hide all the inactive pages, and only keep the active page visible.

Alternatively, if this is not feasible, is it possible to extract all the views that's in the active page?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you thought of using a UICollectionView, restricted to the horizontal axis, and make the pages into custom UICollectionViewCells? It would do all of the heavy lifting for you.

Comment: Great point Stephen. Unfortunately a lot of existing features have been made with a UIScrollView template and cannot be adjusted to collectionView.

Comment: When do you want them to disappear? When the scrolling ends and then appear back when the scrolling starts? Because an inactive page will become active when scrolled (so it should appear somehow), so how do you want it to look?

Comment: @timaktimak Good question, here is the sequence of events: 1. user scrolls and stops at view 2. User activates a feature 3. This feature requires the inactive views be hidden.

Comment: @daspianist so, I assume that the user can not scroll after the feature has been activated? To scroll again he has to deactivate the feature so that all views are back? Or am I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the function below , and adjust it to fit your situation:

```
func disableInactiveView(){
    let offset = scrollView.contentOffset;
    let frame = scrollView.frame;

    let shownFrame = CGRect(x: offset.x, y: offset.y , width: frame.size.width, height: frame.size.height)

    for colorView in scrollView.subviews{
        if shownFrame.contains(colorView.frame) {
            colorView.backgroundColor = UIColor.green;
        }else{
            colorView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding all the views to scrollView is not good for performance. The best solution for managing such view is to use `UICollectionView` with custom `UICollectionViewCell`s. Collection view will do everything you need - reuse your views and place them correctly according to visible rect. In case you cannot use `UICollectionView` try something like that:

```
@interface SampleClass : UIViewController <UIScrollViewDelegate>

@property (nonatomic) UIScrollView *scrollView;
@property (nonatomic) NSUInteger viewsCount;
@property (nonatomic) NSDictionary<NSNumber *, UIView *> *visibleViewsByIndexes;

@end

@implementation SampleClass

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    [self updateViews];
    [self hideInactiveViews];
}

- (void)updateViews
{
    CGPoint offset = self.scrollView.contentOffset;
    CGRect frame = self.scrollView.bounds;
    CGRect visibleRect = frame;
    visibleRect.origin.x += offset.x;

    // Determine indexes of views which should be displayed.
    NSMutableArray<NSNumber *> *viewsToDisplay = [NSMutableArray new];;
    for (NSUInteger index = 0; index < self.viewsCount; index++) {
        CGRect viewFrame = [self frameForViewAtIndex:index];
        if (CGRectIntersectsRect(viewFrame, visibleRect)) {
            [viewsToDisplay addObject:@(index)];
        }
    }

    // Remove not visible views.
    NSDictionary<NSNumber *, UIView *> *oldVisibleViewsByIndexes = self.visibleViewsByIndexes;
    NSMutableDictionary<NSNumber *, UIView *> *newVisibleViewsByIndexes = [NSMutableDictionary new];
    for (NSNumber *indexNumber in oldVisibleViewsByIndexes.allKeys) {
        if (![viewsToDisplay containsObject:indexNumber]) {
            UIView *viewToRemove = oldVisibleViewsByIndexes[indexNumber];
            [viewToRemove removeFromSuperview];
        } else {
            newVisibleViewsByIndexes[indexNumber] = oldVisibleViewsByIndexes[indexNumber];
        }
    }

    // Add new views.
    for (NSNumber *indexNumber in viewsToDisplay) {
        if (![oldVisibleViewsByIndexes.allKeys containsObject:indexNumber]) {
            UIView *viewToAdd = [self viewAtIndex:indexNumber.unsignedIntegerValue];
            viewToAdd.frame = [self frameForViewAtIndex:indexNumber.unsignedIntegerValue];
            [self.scrollView addSubview:viewToAdd];
        }
    }
    self.visibleViewsByIndexes = newVisibleViewsByIndexes;
}

- (CGRect)frameForViewAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
    // Return correct frame for view at index.
    return CGRectZero;
}

- (UIView *)viewAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
    return [UIView new];
}

- (void)hideInactiveViews
{
    CGPoint offset = self.scrollView.contentOffset;
    CGRect frame = self.scrollView.bounds;
    CGRect visibleRect = frame;
    visibleRect.origin.x += offset.x;

    for (UIView *view in self.visibleViewsByIndexes.allValues) {
        if (CGRectContainsRect(visibleRect, view.frame)) {
            // Active view.
            view.alpha = 1;
        } else {
            // Inactive view.
            view.alpha = 0.2;
        }
    }
}

@end
```